# Google Map Marker at the Map Centre is not at actual Location

Tags: android, google-maps

I have tried many methods around the stackoverflow but I am not able to get the my Marker which is aligned centre in layout. The marker is always below the actual geo-point. I have a marker which is at the actual geo-point. But the marker in the centre of the layout is not at the actual geo-point location.

Here is the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="in.gitbox.cabtap.rider.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fixed_pin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/map_pin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <include layout="@layout/places_search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/folding_cell_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/follow_user_fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/folding_cell"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_black_24dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:focusable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the screenshot of the pins on the device.

[image: There basically two pins the one which is generated Marker and below one is the marker image centred in layout]

My original marker is at the exact geo-point location but the marker which I am using at centre layout is not at the exact geo-point. Kindly let me know if there is a work around this with CameraUpdate or some other tweaks.

Comment: did you tried margin for marker from bottom 1/2 height of marker drawable?

Comment: @kulvinder doesn't work that way

Comment: I'm using Framlayout instead relativeLayout that may be the reason its working for me..you can also try by replacing relativelayout with framelayout...

Comment: FrameLayout with what parameters?

Comment: @kulvinder thanks it did work after using foregroundGravity but some negligible point away from the geo-point but still it's workable thanks a lot

Comment: The markers anchor point is playing role here as well - another way to adjust its position.  You might try an anchor of 0.5,1.0 (middle-bottom).